# Determining the criteria for a population to survive in "long time".

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2(x-\gamma)(1-x)$$

and I am being asked to determine the criteria for the population to survive in the limit of long time?

I assumed that I needed something in terms of time(Genius).

I obtain this 
$$\frac{1}{\gamma x} + \frac{1 + \gamma^2}{\gamma^2(1-\gamma)}ln(|x-\gamma||1-x|) = t + c$$

This would be great, except for that first term. I have tried substituting in $x = ln{e^x}$ and got a horror story.

I have never tried this before, but could I solve $\frac{dt}{dx}$ then rearrange?

Comment: how do you derived your solution?

Comment: Separation of variables, then expressed the reciprocal in $x$ as partial fractions.

Comment: in this case i got this here $${\frac {\ln  \left( -1+x \right) }{-1+\gamma}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( x
 \right) }{{\gamma}^{2}}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\gamma}}+{
\frac {1}{\gamma\,x}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( x-\gamma \right) }{ \left( -
1+\gamma \right) {\gamma}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: I treated the square term as a linear term... Thank you. If you post that in an answer I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to solve the equation outright in order to understand the long-term behaviour. Sketch the graph of $\dot{x}$ and argue what value $x$ tends to for different initial conditions. I'll give you some hints if needed.

**EDIT:** Answer should be:

If $x_0 = 0, 1, \gamma$ then $x$ has this value $\forall t$.

For $\gamma \leq 0$ then $x \to 1$, $\forall x_0 > 0$.

For $\gamma \in (0,1)$:

- $x \to 0$ for $x_0 \in (0,\gamma)$
- $x \to 1$ for $x_0 > \gamma$

For $\gamma =1$:

- $x \to 0$ for $x_0 \in (0,1)$
- $x \to 1$ for $x_0 > 1$

For $\gamma > 1$:

- $x \to 0$ for $x_0 < 1$
- $x \to \gamma$ for $x_0 > 1$

Comment: +1. I didn't think of doing that. I shall sketch and see what I can determine.

Comment: I am starting to see the advantage of your solution. I cant obtain an explicit equation giving x in terms of $t$. From the graph I can see that If $x > \gamma$ then the population will increase to 1. (I have used change of variables here, so I should be saying population ratio?). However if x is less that $\gamma$ then the population will tend to extinction. Is that along the lines of what was needed?

Comment: Edited answer to give the full solution. In intervals where $\dot{x}>0$, $x$ must increase until $\dot{x} = 0$ or it blows up, and conversely for intervals with $\dot{x} < 0$.